# FromSqlInterpolated and in clause

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, .net-core

sonar is given me a hard time because the following code:

```
        var listaChaves = chaves.ToList();
        var parametros = new string[chaves.Count];

        var parametrosSql = new List<NpgsqlParameter>();

        for (int i = 0; i < listaChaves.Count; i++)
        {
            parametros[i] = string.Format("@param_{0}", i);
            parametrosSql.Add(new NpgsqlParameter(parametros[i], listaChaves[i]));
        }

        var comandoSql = string
            .Format("SELECT distinct on(chave_identificacao) chave_identificacao, data from ultimos_acessos where chave_identificacao in({0}) order by chave_identificacao, data desc",
                string.Join(", ", parametros));

        var ultimosAcessos = await Entidade.FromSqlRaw(comandoSql, parametrosSql.ToArray())
            .Select(a => new ProjecaoListagemUltimoAcesso(a.Data, a.ChaveIdentificacao))
            .ToListAsync();
```

it thinks a sql injection can happen because the string interpolation. So i tried to change to "FromSqlInterpolated" method, as follow:

```
        var listaChaves = chaves.ToList();

        var ultimosAcessos = await Entidade.FromSqlInterpolated(@$"SELECT distinct on(chave_identificacao) chave_identificacao, data from ultimos_acessos where chave_identificacao in({string.Join(", ", listaChaves)})) ) order by chave_identificacao, data desc")
              .Select(a => new ProjecaoListagemUltimoAcesso(a.Data, a.ChaveIdentificacao))
              .ToListAsync();
```

But it just dont work, anyone can help me on how can I create a secure sql from a interpolated string using a "in" clause?

Comment: If postgres doesn't have a table-value parameter feature like MSSQL does then you could dynamically create parameters for each item in `listaChaves` and dynamically create the SQL with an `OR` condition for each, which is what the database engine will do anyway.

Comment: @Crowcoder thanks! But could you give me an example of how the code would like? It isn't very clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. Build an `OR` clause in the same loop as your parameters and stuff it into your SQL:

```
string ORclause = "";

for (int i = 0; i < listaChaves.Count; i++)
{
    ORclause += $" chave_identificacao = @param_{i} OR ";
    
    parametros[i] = string.Format("@param_{0}", i);
    parametrosSql.Add(new NpgsqlParameter(parametros[i], listaChaves[i]));
}

//remove last "OR"
ORclause = ORclause.Substring(0, s.Length - 4);

@$"SELECT distinct on(chave_identificacao) chave_identificacao, data 
from ultimos_acessos 
where {ORclause} 
order by chave_identificacao, data desc";
```

If you have a lot of listaChaves then consider using StringBuilder instead of +=